# CodeIgniter: Including a php script inside the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a function inside my controller that outputs html elements to a view. This is how it looks like.

```
function show_res() {
    $output = '';

    foreach($data->result() as $row) { 
        if($row->user_agency == $user_agency) {
            $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row->user_name.' '.$row->user_lname.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->user_type.'</td>
                    <td>
                        <button>Edit</button>
                        <button>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

My task is that I need to include a php function for when the delete button is clicked, so far this is what I've tried:

```
  if($row->user_agency == $user_agency) {
      $output .= '
               <tr>
                <td>'.$row->user_name.' '.$row->user_lname.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->user_type.'</td>
                <td>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().delete_c/delete_user/.$row->user_id; ?>">
                        <button>Delete</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
```

and

```
if($row->user_agency == $user_agency) {
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row->user_name.' '.$row->user_lname.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->user_type.'</td>
            <td>
                <button>Edit</button>
                <a href="'.echo base_url().'delete_c/delete_user/'.$row->user_id'">
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

The problem with the first one is that the whole

`<?php echo base_url().delete_c/delete_user/.$row->user_id; ?>`

is added as a string instead of a php script so when I click on the button it would redirect to this URL

`https://localhost/test/<?php%20echo%20base_url().delete_c/delete_user/.$row->user_id;%20?>`

As for the second one, it causes an internal error resulting to the status code 500

Comment: Post your whole code to help you.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin what seems to be lacking? I limited my post to the specific function since it was the only part that seemed to be related to the problem.

Comment: whole code of `<a href="'.echo base_url().'delete_c/delete_user/'.$row->user_id'">
    <button>Delete</button>
</a>` ; before and after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. There is no need to write again PHP start because you already started and you forgot to mention `.` operator.

```
<a href='.base_url().'delete_c/delete_user/'.$row->user_id.'> <button>Delete</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work.

```
<a class="btn" href='.base_url().'delete_c/delete_user/'.$row->user_id.'>
    Delete
</a>
```

500 error code may be cause of you forgot to put `.` in string concatenation or may be undefined variable used in function.